# Simulation of tuned circuit with initial inductor current gives flat zero

Tags: simulation, inductor, spice

I'm playing with ngspice, and wondered if I could get a signal out of a simple RLC circuit using an inductor with initial current.  There are no power or current sources.  The results aren't what I expect, probably because I did something blatantly stupid and not seeing it.

My .cir file:

```
simple RLC with initial inductor current
C1  1 0   22uF
L1  1 0   6mH    IC=1A
R1  1 0   10kOhm 
.end
```

Using the ngspice command line,

```
tran 100us 20ms
plot v(1)
```

But the plot is flat zero.     Why is that?

I expect the voltage at node 1 to increase from 0V at t=0, peak, and continue on as an exponentially decaying sine.  My tran timing may be whacky off, but I should see *something*, maybe just a linear initial rise, or a spike.

Comment: try running the analysis for 1 second and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.   Need to have "UIC" in the "tran" line.

```
.tran 50us 30ms 0s  500us UIC
```

works fine.

Guess I need to spend more time with the spice user manual.